# What's the difference between /ɪ/ and /i(ː)/?

Tags: english, phonetics

In English there's the vowel sound /ɪ/ as in "bin" and /i(ː)/ as in "been".

My girlfriend, who is Greek, cannot perceive the difference, but to me they sound very different.

Is the difference really only the length of the vowel?

If I hold the vowel in "bin", it doesn't sound at all like "been" to me, but is that down to me starting out knowing what word I'm trying to say, and so I'm primed to hear "bin" over "been"?

Comment: It's perfectly normal for a speaker of a language not having a distinction, to finding very hard to tell the sounds apart. Distinguishing /i:/ from /ɪ/ took me years, and /ɛ/ from /æ/ is still quite hard. On the other hand, I've been told that for English speakers it is hard to distinguish /ɛ/ from /e/, which seems unimaginable to me.

Comment: Your statement that you've been "primed" is very salient. An easy example: do you know/perceive that most English speakers pronounce the /p/ phoneme of the letter _p_ of s*p*in and *p*in very differently?

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed! It sounds the same in my head :D

Comment: Wait, isn't /i:/ the sound in _bean_, not _been_?

Comment: @Hearth: "been" is pronounced the same way as "bean" by some people, particularly in British English.

Comment: @sumelic I never knew that, huh! Thanks for telling me that; now I know I'm not going even further insane.

Comment: @sumelic and Hearth - actually, most speakers *think*  they pronounce *been* like *bean*, but they  actually usually pronounce it like  the word *bin*. It's usually only pronounced *bean* when it's stressed or sometimes when it's stranded - neither of which it usually is! (See note at end of my post)

Comment: @Araucaria: Yes, /ˈbiːn/ is a strong form, like the pronunciations of "was", "what" or "of" with /ɒ/. Most American English speakers have replaced the strong forms of those three words with a "re-stressed" form that has the vowel phoneme /ʌ/, and likewise, /ˈbɪn/ is often used as a strong form in American English, and I believe sometimes in British English.

Comment: @sumelic Yes, that's right. And many speakers, for example myself, have free variation between /bi:n/ and /bɪn/ as a strong form.

Comment: Wait, isn't it 'simply' the difference between the KIT and FLEECE vowels, a [near-high front](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-close_front_unrounded_vowel) and a [high-front](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_front_unrounded_vowel) diphthong (followed by a /j/ glide)? I mean they're distinct for native speakers, but awfully close (despite all the comments that they are 'totally different')

Comment: Classically true of French too (difficult for French speakers to differentiate  /ɪ/ and /i(ː)/). 'bitch' vs 'beach', 'live' vs 'leave'. How to get someone else to hear or pronounce it is a whole nother story, which I presume is the next step. Giving someone knowledge of these things doesn't easily translate to ability.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

No, the difference is not just—or even primarily—one of duration. Although in any given environment /i:/ wil be longer than /ɪ/, their environments radically affect their durations. Because of this, the realisation of /i:/  in some environments will be shorter than that of /ɪ/ in others.

**The difference between realisations of /i:/ and /ɪ/**

Despite the fact that /i:/ for most speakers will be consistently and reliably  longer than /ɪ/ in the same situation, this is not the most significant difference between  the realisations of these two vowels. They are *qualitatively* different.

Just behind your teeth, you can feel it with your tongue, there is a little shelf that slopes slightly upwards. This is your alveolar ridge. Behind this, your mouth suddenly arches upwards to form the roof of your mouth. Now, if you feel just behind this ridge with your tongue you will be able to feel that this part of your mouth is hard and boney. This part of the roof of your mouth is your ʜᴀʀᴅ ᴘᴀʟᴀᴛᴇ. If you carry on exploring further backwards with the tip of your tongue (it gets a bit ticklish) you will feel that the roof of your mouth becomes soft and tissuey. This tissuey part of the roof of your mouth is your sᴏғᴛ ᴘᴀʟᴀᴛᴇ. This change happens about half way back.

When most speakers make an /i:/, that part of their tongue directly below where your hard and soft palate meet rises up very close to the roof of the mouth. If you are an RP (Southern Standard British English) speaker, it will come so close to the roof of your mouth that if it got much closer, it would cause the air passing through to become turbulent and would effectively turn the sound into a consonant. If you speak General American, then the gap between your tongue and the roof of your mouth will be ever so slightly bigger.

For most speakers, when they produce an /⁠ɪ/, the gap between their tongue and the roof of their mouths will be significantly bigger than it would be for /i:/. It will be nowhere near close enough to cause any turbulence. In addition that part of the tongue that will rise up towards the roof of the mouth will be some millimetres further back from that part that would rise up for /i:/.

---

**The Original Poster's partner**

It is important to realise that what I have described are typical realisations . So a given realisation of /i:/ might be varying degrees lower than IPA [i], and a realisation of /ɪ/ might be higher or lower or more front or more back than IPA [ɪ]. (I haven't talked at all about the diphthongalisation of /i:/, because I'm not sure it is helpful here)

The reason that the Original Poster (OP) can hear this difference in vowel quality, but their partner can't, is that in English this difference in vowel quality leads to a difference in meaning. So there are words in English which can be clearly distinguished solely because of this relatively very small difference in the highness and frontness of the vowel produced by a speaker.

However, for a speaker of Greek, both of the sounds that might be produced by an English speaker aiming for /ɪ/ or /i:/ would be understood to be variations of the same Greek phoneme. It is extraordinarily rare for a language to have two separate high front vowels. Whether a (typical) Greek speaker listens to a pronunciation of /ɪ/ or /i:/, their language brain will map both  sounds onto the Greek I phoneme. So, for example, the words *piss* and *peace* will both sound like the word πεις for a Greek speaker, which is the subjunctive of the verb *say*.

However, if an English speaker wanted to help another non-native speaker hear the difference between the two vowels, there usually is a safe way to do so.

A majority of languages have a high front vowel and a mid front vowel. For a vast majority of speakers these would be thought of as I and E respectively. The I vowel in these languages is typically between English /i:/ and  /ɪ/. Greek happens to be one of these languages.

If you want to help such a speaker hear the difference, show them that if you give them a triplet of words such as *beat, bit, bet* (/bi:t, bɪt, bet/, respectively), they will be able to hear that *bit* is closer to *bet* than *beat* is.

---

<sup>**Footnote:**</sup>

<sup>An interesting fact about the phonology of the word *been* in RP: when it is stressed, or occasionaly when it's the last word in a sentence, it's pronounced /bi:n/—just like the word *bean*. However, it is usually neither stressed nor the last word in a sentence. In these circumstances, it is usually pronounced /bɪn/—just like the word *bin*. English is weird, isn't it?</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure about the "usually" part of how "been" is pronounced. It depends on the context and perhaps the English variety. As an Australian in a sentence such as "I've been here before" I always pronounce it in full. It's very hard to introspect about how often I'd reduce it vs pronounce it full across all uses/contexts.

Comment: @hippietrail Yes. This really applies to SSBE (the OP's variety). There's some discussion under the question, further above :).

Comment: In American English *been* is usually /bɪn/ even when stressed .

Answer (score 14):

They aren't just different in length. In fact, depending on the context, an occurrence of the phoneme /i(ː)/ might be phonetically shorter than an occurrence of the phoneme /ɪ/.

Broadly speaking, English /ɪ/ is pronounced as IPA [ɪ], and English /i(ː)/ is pronounced somewhere around IPA [i], [ɪi], [ɪj]. The IPA symbols [ɪ] and [i] represent vowels of different "qualities", not just different lengths. Vowel quality is related to the position of certain parts of the tongue during the pronunciation of the vowel, and it can be thought of as mainly involving two dimensions, "closeness" (also known as "height") and "frontness/backness". These can be plotted against each other to get a  visual depiction of a "vowel space", which is often depicted as a trapezoid or triangle.

- The vowel [ɪ] is opener than [i] (or equivalently, the vowel [i] is closer than [ɪ]). This means that the tongue is supposed to get closer to the top of the mouth when pronouncing [i]. You can express the same idea in different words by saying that the vowel [ɪ] is lower than [i] (or equivalently, that the vowel [i] is higher than [ɪ]).
- The vowel [ɪ] is also generally said to be less front than /i/, although it's a bit harder for me to define what this means in physiological terms. (The simplified explanation is just that the back of the tongue is more involved in pronouncing [ɪ].)

Using a transcription like [ɪi] or [ɪj] for /i(ː)/ represents that the vowels /i(ː)/ and /ɪ/ often differ not only by having different qualities (i.e. different positions in the vowel space), but also by having different "trajectories" for their qualities over time: /i(ː)/ tends to become closer towards the end, with an "offglide" that resembles the approximant /j/  (the "y"-sound of ***y***ellow). The /ɪ/ sound typically doesn't have this y-like offglide. (In some circumstances, /ɪ/ might actually become more open towards its end, which could be transcribed as something like [ɪə]).

We can measure the acoustic quality of a vowel by looking at the position of its "formants" on a spectrogram. For example, the closer a vowel is, the lower its first formant will be. You can see pictures and more explanation on this page: https://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/~robh/howto.html#formants

Answer (score -4):

Let me try to put it simpler:

The difference between /ɪ/ and /i(ː)/ as in bin and bean besides length is that /ɪ/ is 'clear' and the /i(ː)/ sounds a little fricative. You could probably also write bean as /bhɪːn/. It's the same difference as in ton an tone, just more difficult to hear with the i. Bin and pin have pretty much the same difference without the difference in length, if you pronounce pin with an aspirated p.